# Tkinter color name to color object

Tags: python, colors, tkinter

I need to modify a widget's color in some way, for example, to make it darker, greener, to invert it.
The widget's color is given by name, for example, `'orchid4'`.
How do I get RGB values from a color name string?

Comment: First section: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm

Comment: I did try inspecting into the object, looking at widget's config() info, but the colors stored there are still color names if the color was specified in this way. I even tried looking into the color-object class and source code, but that led me to an unreadable .so file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
In [31]: rgb = button.winfo_rgb("orchid4")

In [32]: rgb
Out[32]: (35723, 18247, 35209)
```

where `button` is the name of your widget object.

Comment: What's the range of these numbers? I usually expect colors to be in [0,255].

Comment: These are 16-bit RGB values which range from 0 to 65535. You can divide each value by 256 if you want the 0 to 255 range.