# Python Tkinter: Why doesn't the background option for button work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This here is my code:

```
for i in range(0, len(btn_txt)):
    btns.append(tk.Button(calc, text = btn_txt[i], background = "#CCCCCC"))
    btns[i].grid(column = i % 7, row = i // 7 + 1)
    btns[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, n = btn_txt[i]: get_key(n))
```

Problem: background = "#CCCCCC" does not change the color of my buttons...
I tried looking into the docs of tkinter and did further search but i did not find a solution for it. I hope someone can help.

PS: I am coding on mac

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Your code does work, it's just that `'#CCCCCC'` is a very similar color to that of default. So it's hard to tell the difference.

If you color the *text* instead of the background for example, with `foreground` option, it makes the text 'invisible':

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="asd")

btn['fg'] = '#CCCCCC'

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23744723/7032856) one can inspect RGB values of colors let's see what they yield:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="asd")

default_rgb = btn.winfo_rgb(btn['bg'])
wanted_rgb = btn.winfo_rgb('#CCCCCC')
reference_rgb = btn.winfo_rgb('grey')

print(default_rgb)
print(wanted_rgb)
print(reference_rgb)

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see the two colors, the default `SystemButtonFace` and `#CCCCCC` are very similar especially when you think of how close of a reference grey is and how far its rgb values are.

---

See below example for an easy to tell coloring:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Colors")

#when button isn't pressed
btn['fg'] = 'orange'
btn['bg'] = 'blue'

#when button is pressed
btn['activeforeground'] = 'red'
btn['activebackground'] = 'green'

btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```